# Should return statement in a view go to end or in middle?

Tags: python, django, view

I tried to find some sort of consistent rule on this but couldn't find one, so I turn to StackOverflow

In Django views, what is considered a better practice: a return statement in middle of view (for example, if-else statement) or at the end of the few? For comparison, consider following hypothethical situation, where the response type needs to change based on some arbitary condition:

```
def example(request):
  response = HttpResponse(content='500 Server error', status=500)
  if request.user.username == 'wolf':
    response = HttpResponse(content='No, bad wolf, no access', status=403)
  elif request.method == 'GET':
    response = render(request, 'barn/barn.html')
  else:
    data, status = get_barn_data(request.POST)
    response = JsonResponse(data=data, status=status)
  return response
```

vs

```
def example(request):
  if request.user.username == 'wolf':
    return HttpResponse(content='No, bad wolf, no access', status=403)
  elif request.method == 'GET':
    return render(request, 'barn/barn.html')

  data, status = get_barn_data(request.POST)
  return JsonResponse(data=data, status=status)
```

Which one of these would be preferred? Django tutorials seem to jump between two variants.

Comment: `return` inside of `if` seems clearer to me.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you use whatever you find the most manageable.

Personally I prefer your second example as it's more clear that you are returning at that point and no futher code/checks will be executed.

Comment: This would be my opinion as well, I see return statement and I know that rest of the code is not going to be executed, but every linter I have throws hissyfit at the idea :/